# Is binary identical output possible with XlsxWriter?

Tags: xlsxwriter

With the same input is it possible to make the output binary identical using XlsxWriter?

I tried changing the *created* property to the same date and that helped a little. Still get a lot of differences in *sharedStrings.xml*.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes for identical input, if you set the `created` date in the [worksheet properties](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/workbook.html#workbook-set-properties):

```
import xlsxwriter
import datetime

for filename in ('hello1.xlsx', 'hello2.xlsx'):
    workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(filename)
    workbook.set_properties({'created': datetime.date(2016, 4, 25)})

    worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
    worksheet.write('A1', 'Hello world')
    workbook.close()
```

Then:

```
$ cmp hello1.xlsx hello2.xlsx

# No output. Files are the same.
```

The order in which strings are added to the file will change the layout of the sharedStrings table and thus lead to non-identical files. That is generally the case with Excel as well.

**Note:** This requires XlsxWriter version 1.0.4 or later to work.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the author of the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36844452/1286628) appears to have [repudiated](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/494#issuecomment-377026213) it, it appears to be correct, but not the whole story. I did my own tests on Python 3.7 and XlsxWriter 1.1.2. You won't notice the creation time issue if your files are small because they'll be written so fast their default creation times of "`now()`" will be the same.

What's missing from the first answer is that you need to make the *same number of calls* to the `write_*` methods. For example, if you call [`write`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write) followed by [`merge_range`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-merge-range) on the same cell for one of the workbooks, you need to have the same sequence of calls for the other. You can't skip the `write` call and just do `merge_range`, for instance. If you do this, the `sharedStrings.xml` files will have different values of `count` even if the value of `uniqueCount` is the same.

If you can arrange for these things to be true, then your two workbooks should come out as equal at the binary level.